# Holt-Winters seasonal method doesn't work in a small sample

Tags: time-series, forecasting, exponential-smoothing

I was following the examples provided by [Forecasting: principles and practice](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/7/1). I have modified a little bit the Holt-Winters' example:

```
 aust <- window(austourists,start=2009)
> fit1 <- hw(aust,seasonal="additive")
Error in ets(x, "AAA", alpha = alpha, beta = beta, gamma = gamma, damped = damped,  : 
  You've got to be joking. I need more data!
> fit2 <- hw(aust,seasonal="multiplicative")
Error in ets(x, "MAM", alpha = alpha, beta = beta, gamma = gamma, damped = damped,  : 
  You've got to be joking. I need more data!

>aust
         Qtr1     Qtr2     Qtr3     Qtr4
2009 55.55857 33.85092 42.07638 45.64229
2010 59.76678 35.19188 44.31974 47.91374
```

Of course I understand that the problem is that the time series is too short. But with two previous periods of time the formula has not enough. Reviewing the formula I don't know why it doesn't work with two periods of time.

Answer (score 4):

You have 8 observations, and you are trying to fit a model with 3 smoothing parameters (level, slope and seasonal) and 5 state parameters (level, slope and 3 seasonal states). So you have one observation for each parameter, which is insufficient.